# C# transactionally swap two folder

Tags: c#, filesystems, swap

I have two folder, for example "C:\Working" and "C:\Final". I have a slow procedure that will crunch data received in "C:\Working" when needed.

When the procedure that manipulate data inside "C:\Working" has finished i would like replace the old data (inside "C:\Final") with the latest information into "C:\Working" (the information into "C:\Working" are always complete and up to date).

So basically i would like to :

1. rename "C:\Final" in "C:_Final"
2. rename "C:\Working" in "C:\Final"
3. delete "C:_Final"
4. create "C:\Working" (now empty)

In that way the time in which the application (that use "C:\Final") have to wait is small.

So the only idea that come to mind was the subsequent :

```
Directory.Move("C:\Final\","C:\_Final\");
Directory.Move("C:\Working\","C:\Final\");
Directory.Delete("C:\_Final\",true);
Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\Working\");
```

But i image there are a better approach, this method is a bit triky in my opinion and if there is an issue (moving, deleting or creating) the folder structure remain inconsistent.
So i would ask if there is a better aproach, i hope for a way to atomically swap directory.

Comment: There's not really a way to do this atomically since you're working with the file system, but one thing you could do before starting is backup all the folders before doing any renames/deletes, etc.. Then, if your code fails for some reason, you could just restore your backup.

Comment: There is no way to atomically swap two directories, as it requires at a minimum of 3 steps. Renaming a _directory_ is not atomic, either.

Comment: @dcp so basically there is no way to achieve a better result than the proposed one?

Comment: @Skary - If you're worried about atomic operations, then you should probably use a relational database and store the data there.  That's what they're designed for.  For file system operations, there isn't a way to do atomic operations.

Comment: @dcp what you mean so is "yes, there is not a better way to do so with a FileSystem". Thanks for the clarification. Ps : unfrotunately there are legacy application and situation (small budget) in which you have no room to follow your design choiche, but have to deal with what there is already in place.

Comment: @gunr2171 - what the heck do you mean by "renaming a *directory* **isn't** atomic"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of research about NTFS atomic operation and support of NET Framework of such kind of operation, i found out topic that sugget using transaction to implement atomicity among when you deal with file system operation.

Seems also that, even if natively the file system operations do not support transaction; there is a Nuget package (TxFileManager) that is focused on provide transactional support over file system operations.
So a combination of transaction and the package mentioned above should allow atomic operation over file system